# Universal qauntification hypothesis in Coq

Tags: coq, universal, quantifiers

I want to change the hypothesis H from the form below

```
mL : Map
mR : Map
H : forall (k : RecType) (e : String.string),
       MapsTo k e (filter (is_vis_cookie l) mL) <->
       MapsTo k e (filter (is_vis_cookie l) mR)
-------------------------------------------------------
Goal
```

to

```
mL : Map
mR : Map
k : RecType
e : String.string
H : MapsTo k e (filter (is_vis_cookie l) mL) <->
    MapsTo k e (filter (is_vis_cookie l) mR)
-------------------------------------------------------
Goal
```

I think, they can both solve the same goal, but I need the hypothesis in the later form. Or more specifically, further separating k into its elements, like below. How can I change the hypotheses H to these two forms?

```
    mL : Map
    mR : Map
    ks : String.string
    kh : String.string
    e : String.string
    H : MapsTo {| elem1:= ks; elem2:= kh|} e (filter (is_vis_cookie l) mL) <->
        MapsTo {| elem1:= ks; elem2:= kh|} e (filter (is_vis_cookie l) mR)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Goal
```

Answer (score 3):

To do this, you need to have in your context a term `k` of type `RecType` and a term of type `e` of type `String.string`. With this, you can obtain this:

---

Using `pose proof (H k e) as Hke`:

```
mL : Map
mR : Map
k : RecType
e : String.string
H : forall (k : RecType) (e : String.string),
    MapsTo k e (filter (is_vis_cookie l) mL) <->
    MapsTo k e (filter (is_vis_cookie l) mR)
Hke : MapsTo k e (filter (is_vis_cookie l) mL) <->
      MapsTo k e (filter (is_vis_cookie l) mR)
-------------------------------------------------------
Goal
```

Notice that you still have H available.

---

Using `specialize (H k e).`:

```
mL : Map
mR : Map
k : RecType
e : String.string
H : MapsTo k e (filter (is_vis_cookie l) mL) <->
    MapsTo k e (filter (is_vis_cookie l) mR)
-------------------------------------------------------
Goal
```

Notice that H has been specialized, and cannot be specialized again.

---

You cannot "obtain" `k` and `e` from `H` though, this does not make much sense for universal quantification, as these are formal parameters of the term `H` (a function does not carry its arguments, rather it asks for them as input).

You must be mistaken with existential quantification, where you can `destruct` an hypothesis to obtain the witness and the proof that the witness satisfies the property.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I dont have `k` and `e` in the context. I tried a goal of the form `forall (k : RecType) (e : String.string),
    MapsTo k e (filter (is_vis_cookie l) mL) <->
    MapsTo k e (filter (is_vis_cookie l) mR)` with `intros k e`. (**now k and e are in context *) then  `apply H`, but then `k` and `e` re-combines..., which I don't want...

Comment: What you're doing is very confusing and shows that you don't really understand what is going on. Could you provide the shape of your actual goal for instance?

Comment: I am not expert, my questions may be annoying. sorry for that. The goal is: `StringMap.MapsTo zk zv (get_site_cookies (http_s_url p d ru) ckmL) <->
StringMap.MapsTo zk zv (get_site_cookies (http_s_url p d ru) ckmR)` where `zk` and `zv` are key-value strings, `RecType` is a record of five elements (key is one of them) and `get_site_cookies` is a fold with f operating only on 3 elements of `RecType`. `MapsTo` in H in post above is CookieMap.MapsTo... It may be difficult to understand the types/maps, however, I can provide the detailed types/functions, if you need.

Comment: It's ok to be a beginner. Just try to give details to help people help you! So it seems that, if you need to apply your hypothesis `H`, you want to use it on `zk` and `zv` using something such as `specialize (H zk zv).`. However, it gives you a proof of `MapsTo zk zv (filter (is_vis_cookie l) mL) <-> MapsTo zk zv (filter (is_vis_cookie l) mR)`. This is still a far cry from your goal (if `mL` and `ckmL` aren't the same, it might even be useless). Since `get_site_cookies` is a fold, you probably want a proof by induction.